# How to use lasagne with tensorflow-gpu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow

I want to use **lasagne 0.2** that is supported by only python 2.7 and 3.4 but tensorflow-gpu only supports python 3.5 and above. If I use **python 3.7 and lasagne 0.1 then getting this error**.

> C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
>   E:/ci/EvolutionaryGAN-master/test.py WARNING (theano.configdefaults):
>   g++ not available, if using conda: `conda install m2w64-toolchain`
>   C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\theano\configdefaults.py:560:
>   UserWarning: DeprecationWarning: there is no c++ compiler.This is
>   deprecated and with Theano 0.11 a c++ compiler will be mandatory
>   warnings.warn("DeprecationWarning: there is no c++ compiler." WARNING
>   (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to
>   execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will
>   default to Python implementations. Performance will be severely
>   degraded. To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty
>   string. WARNING (theano.tensor.blas): Using NumPy C-API based
>   implementation for BLAS functions. Traceback (most recent call last): 
>   File "E:/ci/EvolutionaryGAN-master/test.py", line 10, in 
>       import lasagne   File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\lasagne__init__.py",
>   line
>
> 19, in 
>       from . import layers   File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\lasagne\layers__init__.py",
>   line 7, in 
>       from .pool import *   File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\lasagne\layers\pool.py",
>   line 6, in 
>       from theano.tensor.signal import downsample ImportError: cannot import name 'downsample' from 'theano.tensor.signal'
>   (C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\signal__init__.py)

Comment: Lasagne is a library to make neural networks in Theano, it does not support TensorFlow

Answer (score 0):

According to [Lasagne](https://lasagne.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#welcome-to-lasagne)

> Lasagne is a lightweight library to build and train neural networks in
> Theano.